# Scheduled task in windows server does not appear in PostgreSQL log file

Tags: postgresql, windows-server, scheduled-tasks

### PostgreSQL 14 - Windows Server 2012

I have a scheduled task every day at 5 AM. It executes an `sql` file with an `update` query and some `refresh materialized views`.

- According to Windows Server, the task is executed without any error.
- In the log file, I can't see any line about the queries written in the `sql` file.
- The views that are supposed to be refreshed are not.
- If I execute all the queries contained in the `sql` file by hand one by one, it works.
- The user executing the task is the same executing all others successfully scheduled tasks, so same password (and no pwd issue in Windows log).

Why is it that, despite the apparent success of the task, the requests don't run?

Comment: What log settings do you have such that you would expect to see logfile entries?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Usually, in the log file, I can read the queries contained by the sql file at the time the task is launched. Now they appear no more. I have scheduled a copy fo the original task at a different time this morning just to see...

Comment: Postgresql usually logs errors, not successful queries.  Do you have log_statements set to all? Some duration-based logging setting?

Comment: log_statements = "none". log_min_duration_statement = 3000; I know that sql is not done because  in my mat views, a field records the day of the refresh, and it is not today.